# Delete Sheet if contains only one column with text

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with multiple sheets.

I want to check if each sheet has more than one column of content. If not delete it.

This would have to be deleted:
[image]

This not:
[image]

Comment: `If IsEmpty(Range("B1").Value) Then`...

Comment: thanks @BigBen, appreciate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code, please.

Edited: In order to answer your last question from the comment, the initial `Sub` will be adapted to call two other subs, able to add numbers to existing headers, in order to make them unique:

```
Sub deleteSheetsOneColumn()
  Dim wb As Workbook, sh As Worksheet, nrCol As Long, i As Long
  Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
  For Each sh In wb.Worksheets
    If sh.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column = 1 Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
         sh.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Else
        'testUniQHeaders sh 'the simple solution (need to uncomment it and comment the next line
         testUniQueH sh 'comment the previous line, to make it working
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

The code will also delete the empty sheets, too...

The next sub will simply add an incremented number to each existing header, making it unique:

```
Sub testUniQHeaders(sh As Worksheet)
 Dim nrCol As Long, i As Long

  nrCol = sh.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    For i = 1 To nrCol
        sh.Cells(1, i).Value = sh.Cells(1, i).Value & " " & i
    Next i
End Sub
```

The next one, will load each column header in a dictionary, in a tricky way and use the result in order to adapt only the headers appearing more then once:

```
Private Sub testUniQueH(sh As Worksheet)
 Dim nrCol As Long, i As Long, dict As Object, strH As String, key As Variant
 Dim arrK As Variant

 Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

  nrCol = sh.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
  'input cols in the dictionary
    For i = 1 To nrCol
        strH = sh.Cells(1, i).Value
        If Not dict.Exists(strH) Then
            dict.aDD key:=strH, Item:=Array(1, i) 'init number plus column number
        Else
            dict(strH) = Array(dict(strH)(0) + 1, dict(strH)(1) & "|" & i) 'add occurrences and col no
        End If
    Next i

    For Each key In dict.Keys
        If CLng(dict(key)(0)) > 1 Then
            arrK = Split(dict(key)(1), "|")
            For i = 1 To UBound(arrK)
                sh.Cells(1, CLng(arrK(i))).Value = _
                    sh.Cells(1, CLng(arrK(i))).Value & " " & i
            Next i
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for that and sorry for my late reply. tested and works as expected. Appreciate.

Comment: @badrhari: Glad I could help!

Comment: sorry if bothering to much, but now facing a new situation. Would be possible to add a counter in a column header if the text is the same? So if I have for example Column | Column| Column, I'd like to have Column 1| Column 2| Column 3. Text already exists there, I just need to make it different there in the header. Hope it makes sense? Thanks

Comment: @badrhari:  I am not sure I understand... So, would you like to rename the columns in each sheet starting from `Column1` to the last existing one (`Columnx`)? But I must close my computer in some minutes. I will adapt the code to work as I explained before. If not convenient, please better explain what you need and I will solve it tomorrow.

Comment: @badrhari: Did you tested the adapted code? Was my understanding correct?

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. Tested it and works, but 1 thing I did not mentioned is that I already have some text in that column header, so I need a counter to be added to the existing header/cell. basically I need to avoid having duplicates in column headers.For example |Horse|Dog|Horse|Cat|, I need it to be |Horse 1|Dog|Horse 2|Cat|. My text there can be any, but can have duplicates while the doc is completed online. I want to avoid duplicate once I download it and start working with it. Many thanks

Comment: @badrhari: OK. In order to have unique headers, keeping your existing ones, it would be enough to add a different number to each of them. I will adapt the code in this way (variant 1). But to add an incremented  number, starting only from the second occurrence, it is a little more complicate. I will also prepare a piece of code, but I would like you to promise that you will do whatever is necessary to prove that you understood it :)

Comment: Many thanks @FaneDuru. Will have the above ones tested and I will do my best to make sure it's all clear about how they were build. New to VBA so be sure it's a very good piece of study for me. I'm enthusiast about how many things can be done with VBA. Cheers mate.